# change all elements with a certain class based on text input

Tags: javascript, html

I think this is going to be something very simple but I haven't found an answer. How would I make all span elements with `class="namehere"` display what was inserted in input text?

```js
function start() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  document.getElementByClassName("namehere").innerHTML = name;
}
```

```html
<input id="name" type="text" value="Type name here">
<button type="button" onclick="start()">start</button>
<br>
<br>
<span class="namehere"></span> is doing this and that.
<br>
<span class="namehere"></span> wants to do this and that.
<br>
<span class="namehere"></span> is not doing this or that.
<br>
<span class="namehere"></span> wants to do this but instead is doing that.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in jQuery, it will help you a lot with this kind of solution.

You need to include `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>` in your header and change your code to that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>test</title>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="name" type="text" value="Type name here">
    <button type="button" onclick="start()">start</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="namehere"></span> is doing this and that.
    <br>
    <span class="namehere"></span> wants to do this and that.
    <br>
    <span class="namehere"></span> is not doing this or that.
    <br>
    <span class="namehere"></span> wants to do this but instead is doing that.
    <script>
     function start(){
         var name = $("#name").val();
          $(".namehere").text(name);
     }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you David Rissato this is exactly what i was looking for i will look in to jquery.

Answer (score 5):

The [method `getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object of elements.

You need to iterate over each element and access it by its index.

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5amwxgz/)

```
var nameElements = document.getElementsByClassName('namehere');
for (var i = 0; i < nameElements.length; i++) {
    nameElements[i].textContent = document.getElementById('name').value;
}
```

or:

```
var nameElements = document.getElementsByClassName('namehere');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(nameElements, function (el) {
    el.textContent = document.getElementById('name').value;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Josh Crozier I totally get this answer but how come it  doesnt work in the example?

Comment: I've also made a demo for this question. The output of my code is correct, but a TypeError is thrown every time the `start` button is clicked. What's the reason for that error? http://jsbin.com/qemizacoxe/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I clicked on "Working Example" and  in http://jsfiddle.net/jL6L6j9f/ when i clicked on start  it didnt do anything, i copied your code in to my html and it didn't work either. thank you

Comment: @HK0 Ah, it was working in Chrome, but not Firefox. It's updated now. Thanks for pointing that out, it should work.

Comment: @JoshCrozier I was actually talking about my demo. I've provided the link to it in my previous comment.

Comment: @Arjun It's because you are going out of the bounds of the array. You changed the condition `i < nameElements.length` to `i <= nameElements.length`. Updated example - http://jsbin.com/zisakotepo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Oh! A silly mistake. I forgot that the last element of an array is always at `array.length - 1` not at `array.length`. Thank You. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of elements with a certain class name with `document.getElementsByClassName(name)` just as you did, so thats fine.

It returns an array tho, so you actually will have to loop through that.

Answer (score 0):

hello HK0 as far as I can remember the document.getElementByClassName can not reach the innerHTML (or at least not directly) so I suggest an easier approach of the matter by using a simple for method and getting the elementbyid like te following:

```
 <span id="namehere0"></span> is doing this and that.
 <br>
 <span id="namehere1"></span> wants to do this and that.
 <br>
 <span id="namehere2"></span> is not doing this or that.
 <br>
 <span id="namehere3"></span> wants to do this but instead is doing that.

 <script>
 function start(){
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  for(var i=0;i<4;i++) document.getElementById("namehere"+i).innerHTML=name;

  }
        </script>
```

hope this helps

Comment: there is no problem with jquery of course but if you just need to do simple things it would be better not to have 2 use all of the jquery library for that as it would be a waste of performance and so on.

Comment: In this particular case is ok but you are right youhanna